# PopupMenuの選択時の背景色変更について

Tags: java, android, xml

PopupMenuの選択時の背景色変更について、スタイルに「listselector_popup.xml」を適用して
実現したい。
現状のままでは「@color/dialog_background_color
」が適用されるだけで、選択しても「listselector_popup.xml」は適用されない。
※背景色は黒に近いグレーとしたが、選択時はAndroid4.4.4では薄いグレー、Android8では黒となり、
Android8のときに変化を感じないため、自分で指定したい。

なお、以下の回答を参考にソースを直しても変化はない。
[Android: background color when menu item is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585045/android-background-color-when-menu-item-is-pressed/35749206#35749206)

```xml
styles.xml

    <!-- ポップアップテーマ -->
    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/dialog_background_color</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/listselector_popup</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/CustomListView2</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomListView2" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/listselector_popup</item>
    </style>
```

```xml
listselector_popup.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/listselect_dialog_color" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@color/listselect_dialog_color" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/listselect_dialog_color" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/listselect_dialog_color" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@color/listselect_dialog_color" />
</selector>
```

```java
//java
        // PopupMenuのスタイル設定
        Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.PopupMenu);
        // PopupMenuのインスタンスを作成
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);
```

Answer (score 1):

以下で実現できました。
PopupMenuはitemで定義してるし、itemBackgroundですよね。。

```xml
styles.xml
    <!-- ポップアップテーマ -->
    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/dialog_background_color</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/listselector_popup</item>
    </style>
```